# How to centre a UL ID Sub-nav

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create a menu bar with a sub-nav under some parents, however the childs are not aligning.
I have change the child bicolour to red to highlight the concern.
There is a chance that by entering the sub-nav text may cure the concern.

I have listed below the CSS and HTML.

Kind regards
Gary.

[Danceblast](http://www.danceblast.myfreeola.uk/template.html)

Comment: Please share your whole code here (preferably via jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
#dropnav ul li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

It's being applied to the subnav's child li's aswell, you can target the subnav directly and set the margin to 0

```
#subnav li {
   margin-left:0px !important;
}
```

OR

```
#dropnav #subnav li {
   margin-left:0px;
}
```

if you dont want to use `!important`.

Comment: Thank you very much Phil M and Antonio Smoljan. Very quick responses.

Comment: Np, if the answer helped in any way be sure sure to vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
#dropnav ul li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

You want to remove the margin as well as you want to check for your text-alignment.

At the moment your elements use

```
text-align: center;
```

on all its parents and childs. You probably want that to be:

```
text-align: left;
```

Hope that helps.